# Convert Objects.ObjectResult<result> to object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a repository in asp.net MVC

I the repository I call on the stored procerdure to get object, but I get the `Objects.ObjecResult<result>` and i do not know how to make it into a Producer object

```
 Entities enteties = new Entities();
 Product contact = (Product)enteties.uspGetProduct(productId);
```

I get te following error
Cannot convert type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult' to 'Models.Product'

Comment: System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<Models.uspGetProduct_Result>

Comment: I am dealing with auto generated databasemodel class

Comment: Have you tried changing the result of the stored proc from the autogenerated result to the entity type you want it to return. If I understand correctly you added a stored proc and the return type was generated for you but in reality what the stored procedure returns is an entity that you already have (thus all the properties of the autogenerated entity are the same as in the existing entity). You want be able to cast/convert it without copying all the values. Since you already have the type you want you should use it as the return type and remove the autogenerated type altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When using store procedure in entity framework it returns `ObjecResult<result>` so you need to cast it your required type. You can cast using Select operator as below :

```
return query.Select(x=> new Product {
// Assign properties here 
Id = x.Id
}).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is:

If your Stored Procedure returns a single element of type Product

```
Entities enteties = new Entities();
var data = enteties.uspGetProduct(productId).GetEnumerator();
if(data.MoveNext())
    Product contact = enteties.uspGetProduct(productId).GetEnumerator().Current;
```